# Postgres DISK IO very high

Tags: performance, linux, hardware

I have very little experience in database administration, so I would like to ask you for help. I'm working on a home project that collects product information from one of the marketplaces.
I'm inserting approximately 700 records into a table
[image]
with the following structure
[image]

If you look at the number of disk operations using iotop, on average it is 10-15 M/s,
[image]
the same data can be seen in the Proxmox interface.
[image]

Why are there so many disk insert operations? After all, a record in a table has only a few fields. My nvme ssd spends about 1tb+ of resource per day. Although the database size increases by ~2GB. My consumer grade SSD won't last that long)
Tell me, what am I doing wrong? Or is this normal postgres behavior. Thank you.